# React.js Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, webpack

After getting frustrating from the react_rails gem because of the lack of support for Commonjs modules, i'm testing the [react_webpack_rails](https://github.com/netguru/react_webpack_rails) gem from netguru. but since then i got an Invariant Violation.

For example, if i'm writing a simple Hello World component in ES6 syntax :

```
import React from 'react';

class tasksBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello World</div>;
  }
}

export default tasksBox;
```

raise these errors :

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

your help will be much appreciated, i can't figure where the error come from.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code there so the problem is elsewhere

Comment: How exactly are you trying to render `tasksBox`?

Comment: If changing the capitalization really fixes the issue, then your actual code must be different.

Comment: nop, i created a new app with only this component. The setup i'm using can be found there https://github.com/netguru/react_webpack_rails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of your react component is invalid. It must be capitalized like so:

```
export class TasksBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello World</div>;
    }
}
```

You can export the class inline. Notice I changed the name to start with a capital letter `TasksBox` instead of `tasksBox` as React wants your class name to start with a capital letter

---

EDIT: if your example has no state or other custom defined functions you dont need this to be a React Class.. but rather it can be a Stateless Function/Component like so

```
export default (props) => {
    return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```

Comment: No need to call `super()` if you don't override the constructor. The capitalization of the class name doesn't matter either, it matters in JSX, but we don't see how `tasksBox` is rendered.

Comment: @FelixKling you dont have a state on the class if you dont override the constructor if im not mistaken right? theres also a few other things that were recommended in the answer

Comment: See my edited comment regarding the other things. Right, you don't have state, but the component doesn't use state, so that's not a problem. I'm not saying that your suggestions are wrong, I'm implying that they won't solve the problem the user has.

Comment: Yea but that wasn't the only thing I recommended.. I also recommended capital letter on the class name which is the correct answer.. I think using the constructor is a must since any practical react class uses it and it makes more sense

Comment: *"since any practical react class uses it "* Not at all. Stateless components are preferred. And as I said in my first comment: *"The capitalization of the class name doesn't matter either, it matters in JSX, but we don't see how `tasksBox` is rendered"*. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/rprwgv52/ . Of course if the OP actually has different code then it *may* be related to the class name capitalization. But the example given in the post certainly does not require it. If the OP uses `import Foo from './tasksBox'; /* ... */ <Foo />` then it will work just fine without changes.

Comment: There is a typo in the example. Should be `constructor`

Answer (score 8):

Well, the answer was very simple, needed to put the first letter of the classname in capital letter. 
and everything went well.

```
import React from 'react';

class TasksBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>blabla</div>;
  }
}

export default TasksBox;
```

thanks for your help guys.

Comment: that was a specification in my answer

Comment: sorry missed that. other comments were true too by the way the class below was just a naked example. your answere were accepted :)

Comment: That is not correct. The problem doesn't lie in this component. As you can see, class names don't have to be capitalized: https://jsfiddle.net/rprwgv52/. The fact that the error says "...but got: undefined" rather points to that you didn't import the component correctly.

Comment: Well since you're working at Facebook, i'm sure you are correct. but nothing else was changed in the code, only the name of the class. but it was changed also in my index.js were i import all the components and in the rails helper in the html file. i'm sure then that the capitalization has an importance somewhere

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question but I just ran into this issue when trying to use the react-bootstrap component library.

I was attempting to import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap' using the new import syntax `import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap'` and the problem was that I needed curly braces around DropdownButton like so: `import { DropdownButton } from 'react-bootstrap'`